# What are the reasons a package would be de-listed from Bower package manager search feature on the Bower.io website?

Tags: bower

What are the reasons an open source package would be de-listed from Bower package manager?

I registered a package that hasn't gained any traction, but not sure why it would be de-listed from the website twice now.

Not sure if the code needs to have certain specs or what.

**Edit:** Turns out I'm still able to get the package using Bower. 
Does Bower.io remove packages from the search feature of their website if it hasn't been modified recently or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems its a problem at Bower.io site, that even after registering some times you can see the package name in search results and some you just cant(also seems the button search itself doesnt work).
So to find out the search result simply hit this url

http://bower.io/search/?q=`<packageName>`

Example: http://bower.io/search/?q=jRCarousel

And see the search result